# Adding custom button to custom object in lightning

Tags: docusign, compile-error

Followed instruction from [DocuSign](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/dfs-admin-guide-add-send-with-ds-button-to-salesforce-custom-object-v7) to add custom button to custom layout in lightning. Any idea why it may not be working? I'm in Sandbox environment.

Error:

> Error: Syntax error

Code:

```
{!URLFOR(‘/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope’, null, [SourceId = YourCustomObject__c.Id])}
```

Comment: Docusign [Contact Support](https://support.docusign.com/en/contactSupport) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have copied the exact snippet from the link you have provided, with `‘’` characters in `‘/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope’`, resulting in syntax error.

---

Change the text to be enclosed in single quote `'` character as below, and it should work:

`'/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope'` (notice the enclosing single quote `'` character)

Comment: yeah, I noticed that after I posted the question. You were right. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I have a similar question, my url works fine without if else but when I put the same url in an else condition it says the url no longer exists, I need the docusign button to be clickable only after a specified condition, in this case after the opp is more than 50% or so, how can I make this work?